# can i make sure multiple invalidate are not coalesced?

Tags: android, ondraw, invalidation

It seems that multiple `invalidate` will be coalesced for performance issues, but i'm encountering a case where this optimization will cause problems.

Say i have a custom view and it captures `keydown` and `keyup` event. in keydown, the view is in blue and in keyup it becomes red. But sometimes during the `down` and `up` processing, the `onDraw` will only be called once, it is likely because the two invalidate are coalsced. The result is that the view never becomes blue.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Layout should happen very fast, even if it is said `at some point in the future` in the documentation.

Therefore, missing some event as you said implies that the redraw happens so late after being requested that the user *see* it, likely 1 second.
This hypothesis is only possible if you make huge work on `Ui Thread`, or something in your app slows the `Ui Thread` abnormaly.

So these considerations aren't to be taken into account in my opinion.
You should track the current color of your view using a `boolean` and when the view is actually drawn in the future, just draw it in the current color.
Changes being *missed* this way, should indicate they happenned so fast that the user cannot see them, which seems hard because the state of your view is based on user input.

Comment: in fact all i did in `keydown` processing is to change the color and `invalidate`. I think the reason should be the tow invalidate event are so "near" with each other.

Comment: How do you effectively change the color ? Did you notice the behavior you mentioned in your question ?

Comment: at most time the behavior is correct, but at some point(especially just after my activity starts), my view remain red. I add log calls in `onDraw` but in that cases there's only one output.(of course, should be two)

Comment: I believe setting the color should happen inside the Ui Thread, that is, inside `onDraw`